# connecting to both the internet and a local network using opensuse

Tags: networking, opensuse

I have a network as follows:

`192.168.1.0/24 -> Switch -> 192.168.10.0/24`
and
`Switch -> Router 192.168.1.254 -> Internet (ADSL)`

All computers are linux (opensuse for .1.0/24, rhel for .10.0/24).

I am trying to get 192.168.1.101 to be able to connect to both 192.168.10.* and to the internet.

Currently, I can either get it to connect to the internet, or .10.*, but not both simultaneously.

ifconfig from .101:

```
ifconfig
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 18:03:73:1F:85:F1  
          inet addr:192.168.1.101  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::1a03:73ff:fe1f:85f1/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:818382 errors:0 dropped:91 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:564261 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:973305760 (928.2 Mb)  TX bytes:137340228 (130.9 Mb)
          Interrupt:20 Memory:e1a00000-e1a20000 

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:304526 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:304526 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:239675746 (228.5 Mb)  TX bytes:239675746 (228.5 Mb)
```

route command on .101:

```
route -n
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.1.254   0.0.0.0         UG    100    0        0 eth0
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     100    0        0 eth0
192.168.10.0    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
```

traceroute to 192.168.10.1 from .1.101:

```
traceroute -I 192.168.10.1
traceroute to 192.168.10.1 (192.168.10.1), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
 1  * * *
 2  * * *
 3  * * *
 4  * * *
 5  * * *
 6  * * *
 7  * * *
 8  * * *
 9  * * *
10  * * *
11  * *^C
```

If anyone can explain what I'm doing wrong, I'd be very grateful

Comment: have you set routing also on host on 10.168.10.X network ?

Comment: I don't understand your topology, and how you were expecting it to work.  You have two different subnets, but the router only seems to be connected to one of them.  What's supposed to be doing routing between 192.168.1.0/24 and 192.168.10.0/24?  You have them on the same switch, are you using VLANs or doing multiple IP subnets on the same media?

Comment: The .10.x network doesn't need to go out to the internet, so it just ignores the router. We're not using VLANs, just multiple IP subnets into the same switch. I was hoping that we could just set up a routing table entry on each PC that told it where to look for the other network (just go to the switch and find it there)

Answer (score -3):

if you want a local network and internet you need a second network card, plug the local connections into a switch, and the internet connections into the adsl box.
plugging the switch into the adsl box does not work.
Robert.

Comment: According to the question, there is no switch connected to the ADSL box.